# Ember.js tutorial and guide - DS not defined, Ember.State moved to plugin

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to learn Ember, but I'm quickly figuring out that the guide sucks. It leaves out very key components.

I keep getting one of two errors:

> Uncaught Error: Ember.State has been moved into a plugin: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states

and,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DS is not defined

Here is how I have my scripts laid out:

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-states.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The error I get depends if I comment out `ember-data.js` or `ember-states.js`.

In the end, it always errors. Why?

Comment: Hi JDillon, could the two answers below help you in any way? Cheers...

Comment: Not fully. There is a huge descripency between what the guides on Ember's website say and what occurs in v.1.3. However, I give you the answer because you pointed out Yeoman and that takes care of a lot. I also submitted an issue on the Ember.js repo about the lacking documentation and one of them got back to me really quick. So thats a major credit to them. Heres a link to the PR: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4116

Comment: Awesome - glad to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know where you're coming from - similar problems over here, it's a bit bumpy in the beginning.

Finally I used [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) in the end and did the setup using the [yeoman ember-generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember) for doing the project setup and creating models/controller/... have the feeling, it makes things much easier.

The given setup loads the following javascript order (added version numbers manually).

```
   <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script> <!-- v.20.03 -->
   <script src="handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js"></script> <!-- v 1.3.0 -->
   <script src="ember/ember.js"></script> <!-- v. 1.2.0 -->
   <script src="ember-data-shim/ember-data.js"></script> <!-- v. 1.0.0-beta.4 -->
```

Hopefully it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your application adapter e.g `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()`;?
Also when i changed the directions of scripts.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js">  </script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/tags/v1.0.0/ember.js"></script>
```

I also got ds.not defined, when i moved ember-data to the last item on list it got fixed